# Issues using UNWIND to load data to Neo4j using python

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, syntax-error, py2neo

I am trying to load neo4j db using CSV file from python. I am able to connect and load the data without using UNWIND operation. But I want to use it for a faster load. I am getting the following error upon trying to use it.

> {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input '': expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR or AS (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
> " UNWIND {data1} as node"
> ^}
> I have the following code where I am using UNWIND. This is just a small sample I am trying to test out with.

```
cq1=""" UNWIND {data1}​ as node
                        MERGE (n:Person {id : node.ID}​)
                            SET
                               n.gender = node.GENDER"""

list_dicts_data1 = [{"ID": '1',"GENDER": 'Male'}]
graph.run(cq1, data1 = list_dicts_data1)
```

Any suggestions what is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I can't read the error clearly due to bad formatting, but which version of Neo4j are you running? The parameter syntax changed a while ago from `{var}` to `$var`. That might be the cause.

Also, have you considered using py2neo's bulk load API, which wraps this kind of statement for you?
https://py2neo.org/2021.0/bulk/index.html

Comment: Nigel Small - This helped. Changing it from {var} to $var worked